# Change - 'Fiscal Year is based on' Setting - Impacts

Tags: administration

1a) We are using Standard Fiscal Year in Salesforce. Would there be any impact [to reports, forecasts or anything else] if change the 'Fiscal Year is based on' from the starting month to the ending month

1b) Any impact if we change the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a starting month other than January, then changing whether the FY is based on the start or end month would affect all Views, Reports, and Formulas based on relative Fiscal Years (THIS FISCAL YEAR, PREVIOUS FISCAL YEAR, etc.) The FiscalYear value on Opportunity records would likely change.

If you change the Fiscal Start Month, you could also affect relative Fiscal Quarter calculations and fields. A change that keeps quarter boundaries intact, such as from January to April or July, shouldn't affect relative FQ calculations. But changing the fiscal month would, of course, still affect FY-based calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely it has impacts.

From Documentation [Define a Custom Fiscal Year](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_define_cfy.htm&type=0)

> If you change the start or end date of any quarter, period, or week, all forecast data (including quotas, forecast history, and forecast adjustments) that are within that date range, and all forecasts for date ranges automatically adjusted as a result of that change, will be lost. This includes end or start date changes resulting from inserting or deleting periods.

Also, read this: [Set Your Fiscal Year for Customizable Forecasting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_forecastfiscal.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

> Your fiscal year determines your monthly or quarterly forecasting cycle, the month it starts, and whether the Fiscal Year is named for the starting or ending year. For example, if your fiscal year starts in April 2015 and ends in March 2016, your fiscal year setting can be either 2015 or 2016.